# Printing last index of string in a string without using lastIndexOf method

Tags: java, indexof, lastindexof

***Note: This question is asked for a school assignment. I fell I'm getting close to the true code, there are only a few points left to be taken care of.***

I am asked to write a method that receives two strings(s1 and s2) and
checks whether s2 is in s1 case sensitively. If s2 is in s1 it returns the index of the last occurrence of s2, otherwise it returns -1.

So, here is my code:

```
import java.util.*;
public class homework4 {


    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("\nEnter a choice: ");
        int choice = input.nextInt();
        if(choice == 1) {
            System.out.println("Enter firts string: ");
                String s1 = input.next();
            System.out.println("Enter second string: ");
                String s2 = input.next();
            System.out.print(contains(s1,s2));
            }
            else {
                //Call other methods...
           }
    public static int contains (String s1, String s2) {
        for(int i = 0; i<s1.length(); i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j<s2.length(); j++) {
                char ch = s2.charAt(j);
                if(s1.charAt(i) == ch) {
                    return i;
                }
            }   
        }   
        return -1;
    }
```

But this method returns first index of s2 or it is just a copy of IndexOf method. 
Output for `s1 = aabbccbbe` and `s2 = bb` is `2`.

**EDIT :** *@eli's code*

```
import java.util.*;
    public class homework4 {


        public static void main(String args[]) {
            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("\nEnter a choice: ");
            int choice = input.nextInt();
            if(choice == 1) {
                System.out.println("Enter firts string: ");
                    String s1 = input.next();
                System.out.println("Enter second string: ");
                    String s2 = input.next();
                System.out.print(contains(s1,s2));
                }
                else {
                    //Call other methods...
               }
       public static int contains(String s1, String s2) {
        int i = s2.length()-1, j = s1.length()-1;

        if(i > j)
            return -1;

        for(; i > -1; i--) {
            for(; j >= 0; j--) {
                if(s1.charAt(j) == s2.charAt(i)) {
                    if(i == 0)
                        return j;

                    if(j != 0)
                        j--;

                    break;
                } else if(i != s2.length()) {
                    i = s2.length()-1;
                }
            }
        }

        return -1;
    }
```

Comment: `contains("Greetings", "error")` will return `2` I think, even though `"Greetings"` doesn't contain `"error"` and it should therefore return `-1`.

Comment: @Gendarme `contains("Greetings", "error")` returned `1`.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. Even more weird. It returns the index in `s1` of the first letter that they both have, in this case `r`.

Comment: might be help  : http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/String.java#String.lastIndexOf%28java.lang.String%2Cint%29

Comment: Think of your strings as array of characters.  Reverse both arrays and find first indexof

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, close any resource you open *when you're done with it*.

```
input.close();
```

If it is allowed you can just use regex:

```
public static int contains (String s1, String s2) {
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(s2+"(?!.*"+s2+")");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(s1);

    if(m.find())
        return m.start();

    return -1;
}
```

The regex pattern is explained [here](http://frightanic.com/software-development/regex-match-last-occurrence/).

With `find()` you make sure that at least one occurrence is present.
As the pattern can result in 1 and only 1 result, you can just ask for the "first index of first occurrence" in the matcher, achieved with `start()`.

**EDIT**
Okay, I can see you can't use anything but `charAt` and `length`.
Here's a different solution without regex, substring, indexOf or what-so-ever:

```
public static int contains(String s1, String s2) {
    int i = s2.length()-1, j = s1.length()-1;

    if(i > j)
        return -1;

    for(; i > -1; i--) {
        for(; j >= 0; j--) {
            if(s1.charAt(j) == s2.charAt(i)) {
                if(i == 0)
                    return j;

                if(j != 0)
                    j--;

                break;
            } else if(i != s2.length()) {
                i = s2.length()-1;
            }
        }
    }

    return -1;
}
```

I must admit I didn't thoroughly test this.

**FINAL**
I've done some minor fixes for you. I don't know  how you were capable of compiling what you edited in your post. Here's a working sample:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class homework4 {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter choice: ");

        switch (input.nextInt()) {
        // If 1 is given as input...
        case 1:
            // As we press "enter" after inputting 1, the newline is read by the
            // scanner. We skip this newline by doing this.
            input.nextLine();

            System.out.println("Enter first string: ");
            String s1 = input.nextLine();

            System.out.println("Enter second string: ");
            String s2 = input.nextLine();

            System.out.println("Result: " + contains(s1, s2));
            break;
        // If 2 is given as input (just for the sake of the example)
        case 2:
            System.out.println("You chose an unimplemented choice.");
            break;
        // If something else is given as input...
        default:
            System.out.println("Nothing to do...");
            break;
        }

        // As Scanner is considered a resource, we have to close it, now that
        // we're done using it.
        input.close();
    }

    // This is the RegEx implementation
    public static int containsRegx(String s1, String s2) {
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile(s2 + "(?!.*" + s2 + ")");
        Matcher m = p.matcher(s1);

        if (m.find())
            return m.start();

        return -1;
    }

    // This is the charAt and length only
    public static int contains(String s1, String s2) {
        int i = s2.length() - 1, j = s1.length() - 1;

        if(i > j || i * j == 0)
            return -1;

        for (; i > -1; i--) {
            for (; j >= 0; j--) {
                if (s1.charAt(j) == s2.charAt(i)) {
                    if (i == 0)
                        return j;

                    if (j != 0)
                        j--;

                    break;
                } else if (i != s2.length()) {
                    i = s2.length() - 1;
                }
            }
        }

        return -1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot but this is not what I'm looking for. This method returns `-1`for any s1 with spaces in it.

Comment: You're doing something very weird then.

Comment: Testing:
String s1 = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.";
String s2 = "the";

Returns (as expected) 31.

Comment: Can you please make an edit in your original post with what you've edited code to (with my solution, that is)?

Comment: I have given a full sample code now. You were missing a bracer for you main method. Also, note how I close the resource at the end, this is what I meant in the first edition of my answer.

Comment: And just for the record, when you edit your original post, do not delete or alter what you originally had written - instead add an "edit" section at the end, where you update the situation with your new code. Otherwise our answers will not make much sense for someone who didn't read your original post.

Comment: I do not know what to say. Because I'm new to Java and I missed some classes, I couldn't understand these custom methods. Sorry for my ignorance and thank you `very++;`(I'm not good at jokes) much! It's totally working.

Comment: I forgot to add the last check (if one string is empty or s2 is longer (and hence can't be present in s1).
if(i > j || s2.length * s1.length == 0). See the code again, I just added it to the final-section.

Comment: OK. I've added that if condition into code. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Say you have the string called `sentence`: *The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.* and you want to find the last occurrence of *"the"*, called `token`.

`sentence.length = 44` and `token.length = 3`

Consider this somewhat java pseudo code:

```
public static int lastIndexOf(String sentence, String token) {
    //The starting index is the first possible location your token could fit
    int startingIndex = sentence.length() - token.length();
    //move backwards one character at a time until you reach 0
    //checking for string fragment that equals your token at each iteration
    for (int i = startingIndex; i >= 0; i--) {
         String fragment = sentence.substring(i, i + token.length());
         if (fragment.equals(token)) return i;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

**EDIT**

Here is the full application using only length and charAt():

```
public class HelloWorld
{
  // arguments are passed using the text field below this editor
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    int indexOf = lastIndexOf("The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.", "the");
    System.out.print(indexOf);
  }

  public static int lastIndexOf(String sentence, String token) {
    int startingIndex = sentence.length() - token.length();
    for (int i = startingIndex; i >= 0; i--) {
        String fragment = substring(sentence, i, i + token.length());
        if (strEquals(token, fragment)) return i;
    }
    return -1;
  }

  public static String substring(String str, int startingIndex, int endingIndex) {
    int size = endingIndex - startingIndex;
    char[] arr = new char[size];

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
      arr[i] = str.charAt(startingIndex+i);
    }
    return new String(arr);
  }

  public static boolean strEquals(String s1, String s2) {
    if (s1.length() != s2.length()) return false;

    for (int i = 0; i < s1.length(); i++) {
      if (s1.charAt(i) == s2.charAt(i)) continue;
      return false;
    }

    return true;
  }
}
```

**EDIT 2**

You also have a bug in the way you are reading your input.  You need to use `input.readLine()` to get the full line.  `input.read` breaks on spaces.  Along those lines, you also need a new scanner for each line you want to read.

**EDIT 3**

Here is the whole source:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class HelloWorld {
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
      Scanner input1 = new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.println("\nEnter a choice: ");
      String s1="";
      String s2="";
      int choice = input1.nextInt();
      if(choice == 1) {
          Scanner input2 = new Scanner(System.in);
          System.out.println("Enter first string: ");
          s1 = input2.nextLine();
          Scanner input3 = new Scanner(System.in);
          System.out.println("Enter second string: ");
          s2 = input3.nextLine();
        }

    int indexOf = lastIndexOf(s1, s2);
    System.out.println(indexOf);
  }

  public static int lastIndexOf(String sentence, String token) {
    int startingIndex = sentence.length() - token.length();
    for (int i = startingIndex; i >= 0; i--) {
        String fragment = substring(sentence, i, i + token.length());
        if (strEquals(token, fragment)) return i;
    }
    return -1;
  }

  public static String substring(String str, int startingIndex, int endingIndex) {
    int size = endingIndex - startingIndex;
    char[] arr = new char[size];

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
      arr[i] = str.charAt(startingIndex+i);
    }
    return new String(arr);
  }

  public static boolean strEquals(String s1, String s2) {
    if (s1.length() != s2.length()) return false;

    for (int i = 0; i < s1.length(); i++) {
      if (s1.charAt(i) == s2.charAt(i)) continue;
      return false;
    }

    return true;
  }
}
```

Comment: Sure, but I'm not allowed to use the built-in String
methods except `charAt` and `length`.

Comment: Sure, but isn't this code return first index of s2? Cause it returns `-1` for `sentence` : _The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog_ . Thanks by the way.

Comment: Thank you so much but it returns -1 when you enter inputs by hand in `int indexOf = lastIndexOf(sentence, token);
    System.out.print(indexOf);` for `sentence` = The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. How to get lastindexof?

Comment: Yes. Sentence comes first and then token.

Comment: Can't use `readLine()` method, it says "undefined for type Scanner".

Answer (score 1):

I think it will boil down to looping through string characters and storing the last index of occurred match. 
Here is not perfect, but simple example without use of `indexOf`:

```
public static int contains(String s1, String s2) {
    if(s1.length() < s2.length())
        return -1;

    int lastOccurrence = -1;
    for (int i = 0; i < s1.length(); ) {
        if (s1.startsWith(s2, i)) {
            lastOccurrence = i + s2.length() - 1;
            i = lastOccurrence + 1;
        }
        else {
            ++i;
        }
    }
    return lastOccurrence;
}
```